# Count records for every month in a year

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with total no of 1000 records in it.It has the following structure:

```
EMP_ID EMP_NAME PHONE_NO   ARR_DATE
1        A        545454 2012/03/12
```

I want to calculate no of records for every month in year-2012

Is there any way that should solve my issue in a single shot?

I tried:

```
select count(*) 
from table_emp 
where year(ARR_DATE) = '2012' and month(ARR_DATE) = '01'
```

Comment: there doesn't appear to be a question?

Comment: see from..... I want to (2nd line) from top for question

Comment: BTW Wrapping columns in functions makes the query unsargable.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would take some time to state your question clearly and then format it correctly to make it readable. In this case, I think you are asking how to count the number of records in each month of one year, based on the ARR_DATE column but this is a guess. If it's correct, check the documentation for GROUP BY, COUNT(), YEAR() and MONTH().

Answer (score 107, accepted):

```
SELECT    COUNT(*) 
FROM      table_emp 
WHERE     YEAR(ARR_DATE) = '2012' 
GROUP BY  MONTH(ARR_DATE)
```

Comment: why quotes around 2012? `YEAR()` returns a number AFAIK.

Comment: @iDevlop I just tested it (`Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5058.0 (X64)`)and it works both with and without the quotes.

Comment: ** eg:- April has not any employee registered.** so that month has 0 counts. how that record adds to the final result.

Comment: @janaka it would be absent from the result, if you're asking how to force it to include April, 0 I think you should ask it as a new question referencing this one

Comment: @Dan Hi Dan, Can you please tell me If I have to find the record between two years such that I have to show the count from Jan 2019  to Dec 2020 for each month seperately

Comment: @AyushSrivastava do you something like `where ARR_DATE between '01/01/2019' and '31/12/2020'` and then `group by year(ARR_DATE), month(ARR_DATE)`?

Answer (score 59):

This will give you the count per month for 2012;

```
SELECT MONTH(ARR_DATE) MONTH, COUNT(*) COUNT
FROM table_emp
WHERE YEAR(arr_date)=2012
GROUP BY MONTH(ARR_DATE);
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8bc34/3).

Comment: I prefer this one as it gives the month number also

Comment: Can i get month name instead of number? Example `Jan`, `Feb`

Comment: use `SELECT MONTHNAME(ARR_DATE) MONTH` to get "January", "February", etc.

Comment: month number is helpful

Comment: This code doesn't work because if there is no records for a given month it will not be displayed.

Comment: This one served my use case, Thank you!

Answer (score 22):

Try This query:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(CASE datepart(month,ARR_DATE) WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'January',
  SUM(CASE datepart(month,ARR_DATE) WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'February',
  SUM(CASE datepart(month,ARR_DATE) WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'March',
  SUM(CASE datepart(month,ARR_DATE) WHEN 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'April',
  SUM(CASE datepart(month,ARR_DATE) WHEN 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'May',
  SUM(CASE datepart(month,ARR_DATE) WHEN 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'June',
  SUM(CASE datepart(month,ARR_DATE) WHEN 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'July',
  SUM(CASE datepart(month,ARR_DATE) WHEN 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'August',
  SUM(CASE datepart(month,ARR_DATE) WHEN 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'September',
  SUM(CASE datepart(month,ARR_DATE) WHEN 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'October',
  SUM(CASE datepart(month,ARR_DATE) WHEN 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'November',
  SUM(CASE datepart(month,ARR_DATE) WHEN 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'December',
  SUM(CASE datepart(year,ARR_DATE) WHEN 2012 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'TOTAL'
FROM
    sometable
WHERE
  ARR_DATE BETWEEN '2012/01/01' AND '2012/12/31'
```

Comment: +1 for avoiding unsargable predicate but should use unambiguous date formats and the OP should avoid `BETWEEN` if `datetime` datatype (OK if `date` datatype)

Comment: Assumed it is date type, since there is no "time" in example data

Comment: It will display total number of records from January to December....Monthwise or not..?

Comment: @manojkumarsingh - It should correctly separate the values by month. I prefer Joachim's query because it is shorter. But both are valid and should produce the same *counts*, just one in rows and the other in columns.

Comment: @Leigh small difference between Joachim's and mine queries is that, mine in extremly faster over very large tables, since it doesn't use GROUP BY ;)

Comment: @cichy - Interesting. I would have thought performance would be similar, since the net effect is similar, but I could be wrong :). If it is really faster, I would be curious to read an explanation of why, so if you know of any links explaining it, feel free to post them.

Comment: @Leigh I don't have any links at the moment. Few years ago i had to use similar query on a table with over 100 milion rows. With Group BY query was running longer than a minute, and with SUM() it was running less than second. As far as i remember it was a matter of using indexes and temporary tables. Sum() was working only on indexes, and group by had to create temporary table etc.

Comment: @Leigh as a clarification, above performance was about MySQL, You can check how it will behave on SqlServer:
MySQL Explain: http://pastebin.com/2yqK9jdW

Comment: How can we make it column wise like
Month | Count columns only

Answer (score 2):

```
select count(*) 
from table_emp 
 where DATEPART(YEAR, ARR_DATE) = '2012' AND DATEPART(MONTH, ARR_DATE) = '01'
```

Comment: Your Query and my query output is same.I want to have a way so that i can get data month wise..!