# MySQL Query Group By Date

Tags: mysql

I have tried various recommendations based off of other posts with no avail.

I have a database scheme of records with a `Created_Date` Key, and Value would be `01/01/2017`

I am trying to query the database records to give a returned count of How many records per month and which month those fall in line with.

With the following

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE MONTH(`Created_Date`), COUNT(*)
FROM `CRM_Leads`
GROUP BY MONTH(`Created_Date`)
```

I return

```
MONTH(`Created_Date`)   COUNT(*)    
          NULL            872
```

I have also tried almost all the variations on the following post

[Count records for every month in a year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9888263/count-records-for-every-month-in-a-year)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are your dates really dates, or are they strings?

Comment: Theyre strings. @Uueerdo

Comment: You will need to convert them to date values before using them with the MONTH function; MySQL provides [STR_TO_DATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) for that; I'd recommend the long term solution as converting the column to a proper date if possible though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assuming your created_date is a string of format ('dd-mm-yyyy') the you should convert as date with str_to_date

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE MONTH(str_to_date(`Created_Date`, '%d/%m/%Y')), COUNT(*)
FROM `CRM_Leads`
GROUP BY MONTH(str_to_date(`Created_Date`, '%d/%m/%Y'))
```

Comment: returns `MONTH(str_to_date(`Created_Date`, '%y-%m-%d'))  COUNT(*)  
NULL 872`

Comment: scheme   17  Created_Date  varchar(15)  latin1_swedish_ci   No  None

Comment: Date is 01/01/2017

Answer (score 0):

For as long as you store date/time information as strings, you will have great difficulty using any date/time specific functions and features. If you are getting NULL from `MONTH(str_to_date(`Created_Date`, '%d/%m/%Y'))` then the `str_to_date` isn't converting the strings to dates and the most likely reason for this is the `d m y` "pattern" is not corrrect.

All you have old us about your "*strings that might be dates*" is that **one of them** looks like this: `01/01/2017`. Now that could be `DD/MM/YYYY` or `MM/DD/YYYY` and we simply cannot tell which one is correct from the single value you have chosen to share with us. **Look for any day value greater then 12** in your data e.g. `17/01/2017 ==> DD/MM/YYYY` **or** `01/17/2017 ==> MM/DD/YYYY`

Once you have made the choice of which pattern your "*strings that might be dates*" follow; apply that pattern in the str_to_date() function. You migh want  to try a few different patterns to get the best one (and these are just 3 of many you could try):

```
# which pattern is best for you?
SELECT Created_Date
     , str_to_date(`Created_Date`, '%d/%m/%Y') "d/m/y"
     , str_to_date(`Created_Date`, '%m/%d/%Y') "m/d/y"
     , str_to_date(`Created_Date`, '%Y-%m-%d') "y-m-d"
FROM `CRM_Leads`
```

You will not have success with your group by query until you choose the most appropriate `d m y` pattern to apply in teh str_to_date function. Note here that you might also have a variety of patterns in your data, in which case you have an even bigger problem to solve.

Once you have made the choice of which pattern your "*strings that might be dates*" follow; apply that pattern in the s`tr_to_date()` function and ONLY THEN your group by query will work.