# how to count a column by month if the date column has time stamp?

Tags: sql

I have two columns in a table:

```
id    date
1     1/1/18 12:55:00 AM
2     1/2/18 01:34:00 AM
3     1/3/18 02:45:00 AM
```

How do I count the number of IDs per month if the time is appended into the date column?

The output would be:

```
Count   month 
3        1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count records for every month in a year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9888263/count-records-for-every-month-in-a-year)

Comment: What is the type of `date` column?  You will be better off to rename it, since `date` could be a keyword.   What RDBMS (SQL flavor) do you use?

Comment: Or you can google [so - sql count per month](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+count+per+month+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Apply a function on the date that gives you the month. Which DBMS are you using? You should find all date functions in the docs. If not, just google 'date functions' plus your DBMS (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, whatever).

Comment: @PM77-1 I am in dremio and have been told I am using ANSI sql

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I am in dremio and have been told I am using ANSI sql

Comment: Look for `DATE_PART`, `DATE_TRUNC` or `EXTRACT` in https://docs.dremio.com/sql-reference/sql-functions/datetime-functions.html. They should all work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ANSI SQL, you would use:

```
select extract(month from date) as month, count(*) 
from t
group by extract(month from date);
```

I think more databases support a `month()` function rather than `extract()`, though.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I got this error `Cannot apply 'EXTRACT' to arguments of type 'EXTRACT(<INTERVAL MONTH> FROM <VARCHAR(65536)>)'. Supported form(s): 'EXTRACT(<DATETIME_INTERVAL> FROM <DATETIME_INTERVAL>)' 'EXTRACT(<DATETIME_INTERVAL> FROM <DATETIME>)'`

Comment: This is the query I have been trying `select extract(MONTH from to_timestamp("date added")), count(id) 
from t
group by extract(MONTH from to_timestamp("date added"))`

Answer (score 0):

you have to extract month and count by using group by

```
select DATE_PART('month', date) as month,count(id) from yourtable
group by DATE_PART('Month', date)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I got this error `Cannot apply 'DATE_PART' to arguments of type 'DATE_PART(<CHAR(5)>, <VARCHAR(65536)>)'`. I am reading that DATE_PART has two parameters, which I am trying to figure out what the second one is.

Comment: I changed the `date_part` to `DATE_PART('month', to_timestamp("date added")`, it says error at the `from` not sure why

Comment: it was a syntax issue but now getting error `Failure while attempting to cast value '1/1/2017 12:55:03 AM' to Integer.`