# Returning a set of datetimes if they dont fit criteria in SQL

Tags: sql, datetime

this is my very first question on Stackoverflow!

I have a database with a datetime PK, the entries are each hour of each day for a whole year, so there should be 8760 entries per year. Now my task is to check if there is indeed 24 entries for each hour of each day for the whole year.

My first idea for handling this problem would be to query each unique day, and return a match if there isent 24 matches of a specific date.

But i am quite unsure of how i should write they SQL, what kind of tools should i use, and is this a good idea to go about it?

Thank you for reading and please ask if you want me to elaborate :)

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using and show sample fo the data.

Comment: [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9888263/count-records-for-every-month-in-a-year/9888386)